# Angular 12 - @Input & @Output vars do not work

Tags: angular, input, output, decorator

When using @Input or @Output communication between newlly created Components, the Flow simpl doesnt work. It is new, before that things worked just fine. I have not instaled anything new, Versions of npm, Node and Angular are as they were. It is happening even at the most simple cases. Did anyone encounter the simmillar behaviour? If so, what should be done? I Work with the environment for a couple of years now, so "basic" things are  in order.

I have tried to add the this type of communication tp previously defined Components and this Work, but not work on newly defined Components.

Comment: we cannot do much to help you if you do not provide an example of your code where the problem is or provide an example on Stackblitz